# Nested, hierarchical data frames in R

Tags: json, r, dataframe, hierarchical-data, hierarchical

I am new to R and I don't want to misunderstand the language and its data structure from the beginning on. :)

My data.frame `sample.data` contains beside 'normal' attributes (e.g. `author`) another, nested list of data.frame (`files`), which has e.g. the attributes `extension`.

How can I filter for authors who have created files with a certain extension? Is there a R-ic way of doing that? Maybe in this direction:

```
t <- subset(data, data$files[['extension']] > '.R')
```

Actually I want to avoid for loops.

Here you can find some sample data:

```
d1 <- data.frame(extension=c('.py', '.py', '.c++')) # and some other attributes
d2 <- data.frame(extension=c('.R', '.py')) # and some other attributes

sample.data <- data.frame(author=c('author_1', 'author_2'), files=I(list(d1, d2)))
```

The JSON the sample.data comes from looks like

```
[
    {
        "author": "author_1",
        "files": [
            {
                "extension": ".py",
                "path": "/a/path/somewhere/"
            },
            {
                "extension": ".c++",
                "path": "/a/path/somewhere/else/"
            }, ...
        ]
    }, ...
]
```

Comment: You got me wrong. I do use `jsonlite` and I do get `data.frame` yet. But now the question how to analyze the data easily and efficiently?

Comment: Would your data be better described as a list?  Data frames are intended for tabular data, but if the structure is more complicated (as in some JSON files) then a list can be more appropriate.

Comment: I added the JSON the data comes from. `files` are becoming a `data.frame` within the containing `data.frame` for all dictionaries. And yes, it is not trivial. :-D

Comment: You don't mean 'nested dataframe', you mean *'dataframe which references other dataframes, e.g. in a SQL-like schema'*. The usual way is to use join operations, e.g. with dplyr package. Store `authors` and `files` in separate tables/dataframes.

Comment: Creating sample data greatly helps in finding a solution

Comment: Hey, what happened to the json? Please put it back :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting, not many people use R to simulate a hierarchical database!

```
subset(sample.data, sapply(files, function(df) any(df$extension == ".R")))
```

Comment: I assume your answer imply that R is maybe not the right tool to choose?

Comment: @MichaelDorner Well, it's not designed for the task, but then it's not really designed for relational data either, and people use it for that all the time. You work with the data you have. R's flexibility as a programming language means it's possible to handle hierarchical data without too many problems.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, this was very helpful. Not too many, but at least enough problems! I think I will go with some database. :)

Answer (score 6):

There are at least a dozen ways of doing this, but if you want to learn R right, you should learn the standard ways of subsetting data structures, especially atomic vectors, lists and data frames. This is covered in chapter two of this book:

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/

There are other great books, but this is a good one, and it is online and free.

**UPDATE:** Okay, this converts your json to a list of data frames.

```
library("rjson")
s <- paste(c(
'[{' ,
'  "author": "author_1",',
'  "files": [',
'    {',
'     "extension": ".py",',
'     "path": "/a/path/somewhere/"',
'   },',
'   {',
'     "extension": ".c++",',
'     "path": "/a/path/somewhere/else/"',
'    }]',
'},',
'{',
'"author": "author_2",',
'"files": [',
'  {',
'    "extension": ".py",',
'    "path": "/b/path/somewhere/"',
'  },',
'  {',
'    "extension": ".c++",',
'    "path": "/b/path/somewhere/else/"',
'  }]',
'}]'),collapse="")

j <- fromJSON(s)

todf <- function (x) {
    nrow <- length(x$files)
    vext <- sapply(x$files,function (y) y[[1]])
    vpath <- sapply(x$files,function (y) y[[2]])
    df <- data.frame(author=rep(x$author,nrow),ext=vext,path=vpath)
}
listdf <- lapply(j,todf)
listdf
```

Which yields:

```
[[1]]
    author  ext                    path
1 author_1  .py      /a/path/somewhere/
2 author_1 .c++ /a/path/somewhere/else/

[[2]]
    author  ext                    path
1 author_2  .py      /b/path/somewhere/
2 author_2 .c++ /b/path/somewhere/else/
```

And to finish the task, merge and subset:

```
   mdf <- do.call("rbind", listdf)
   mdf[ mdf$ext==".py", ]
```

yielding:

```
    author ext               path
1 author_1 .py /a/path/somewhere/
3 author_2 .py /b/path/somewhere/
```

Comment: You can create a list of data.frames, which is probably what you want. A data.frame is actually a list of (usually) atomic vectors, so this is very close to being a data frame of data frames.

Comment: Hmm, not straightforward. Working on it.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which is how to subset a data frame containing a column of data frames (ie, a hierarchical structure).

Comment: It answers the question that he posted and then changed. I am waiting for his response before I delete all this work :).

Comment: See the first comment. He posted a json file to go along with it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data frame `df`, as a CSV, looks like:

```
author,path,extension
john,/home/john,txt
mary,/home/mary,png
```

then the easiest solution is to use the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, author=="john" & extension=="txt")
```

Comment: True, the easiest is `subset`.  But learning the dplyr verbs will help in the long run.  `subset` can cause problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset

Answer (score 2):

I guess `grep()` function in `base` package could be your solution:

```
files <- data.frame(path = paste0("path", 1:3), extension = c (".R", ".csv", ".R")
                    , creation.date = c(Sys.Date()+1:3))

> files
# path extension creation.date
# 1 path1        .R    2015-07-15
# 2 path2      .csv    2015-07-16
# 3 path3        .R    2015-07-17


> files[grep(".R", files$extension),]
# extension creation.date
# 1 path1        .R    2015-07-15
# 3 path3        .R    2015-07-17
```